# How to copy <li> elements using jquery and scatter them as views Using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy

values from the elements declared in jsp and spray them on the screen.

sampe.html

```
 <div class="island_a">
                    <div class="island_b">
                        <ul class="island_c">
                            <li class="aaaaaa">
                                <span class="fitCenter">
                                    <p class="city">[seoul shop]</p>
                                    <p class="store">a_center</p>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li class=bbbbbb">
                                <span class="fitCenter">
                                    <p class="city">[incheon]</p>
                                    <p class="store">b_center</p>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="cccccc">
                                <span class="fitCenter">
                                    <p class="city">[china]</p>
                                    <p class="store">c_center</p>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dddddd">
                                <span class="fitCenter">
                                    <p class="city">[USA]</p>
                                    <p class="store">d_center</p>
                                </span>
                            </li>
```

The sample.html is written like the code above.

I want is to copy aaaaaa, bbbbbb, cccccc, dddddddd from li class and show them on the screen.

**I tried code 1**

```
var listElements = $(".island_a .island_b .island_c .aaaaaa").clone().wrapAll('<li>');
var listElements = $(".island_a .island_b .island_c .bbbbbb").clone().wrapAll('<li>');
var itemHTML = listElements.parent().html(); 
$(".island_a .island_b .island_c").html(itemHTML);
```

Only aaaaaa values of the li class are imported into the screen.

**I tried code 2**

```
var itemList = [];
var $listElements1 = $(".fitWhereWrap .fitWhere .aaaaaa").clone().wrapAll('<li>').push();
var $listElements2 = $(".fitWhereWrap .fitWhere .bbbbbb").clone().wrapAll('<li>').push();
$(".fitWhereWrap .fitWhere").html(itemList);
```

The above code does not work.

Please save me.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(() => {
  $('.fitCenter').each((index, item) => {
    $('body').append(item);
  })
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.